# Generate a random string from alphabet with specific probabilities (issue with randsrc)

Tags: matlab

So I am familiar with randsrc and that I can create from a random alphabet of integers with given probabilities. So lets say I have this alphabet

```
alphabet={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
prob=[0.08167 0.01492 0.02782 0.04254 0.12702 0.02228 0.02015 0.06094 0.06966 0.00153 0.00772 0.04025 0.02406 0.06749 0.07507 0.01929 0.00095 0.05987 0.06327 0.09056 0.02758 0.00978 0.02360 0.00150 0.01974 0.00074];
```

Notice: alphabet is a cell with 1x26 dimensions and prob is 1x26 double array.

I can create a random string like this

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
%find number of random characters to choose from
numRands = length(s); 
%specify length of random string to generate
sLength = 10;
%generate random string
randString = s(ceil(rand(1,sLength)*numRands));
```

The problem with this way is that I can't figure out a way to take the probabilities in to account. So what I have been trying to do is:

```
randomString =randsrc(10,1,[alphabet; prob]);
```

But this gets displayed in console:

```
Error using vertcat 
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent. 
Consider converting input arrays to the same type before concatenating.

Error in test (line 8) 
randomString = randsrc(10,1,[alphabet; prob]);
```

In this if I do:

```
alphabet = [097:122];
```

the randsrc will work.

But what ever I try I can't give the randsrc character alphabet. The reason I want to give the randsrc character alphabet is because my alphabet can be a lot more complicated that the first one, like this:

```
alphabet = {'aa','ab','ac'...'az','ba','bb','bc'...);
```

Is there anyway that I could make the randsrc get character alphabet and not integer. Or should I try to create my own function to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `randsrc` to generate random indices into `alphabet`:

```
indices = randsrc(10,1,[1:numel(alphabet); prob]);
randomString = [alphabet{indices}];
```

Comment: From someone who has missed his holidays for an equivalent project, man I owe you a beer!!! Thanks and happy holidays.

Comment: @ceid-vg: I’ll open one this afternoon and pretend you’re buying. ;)